# Apache Zeppelin - Zeppelin tutorial failed to create interpreter - Connection refused

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to test Zeppelin 0.6.2 with a Spark 2.0.1 installed in a Windows Server 2012.

I started the Spark master and tested the Spark Shell.
Then I configured the following in the conf\zeppeling-env.cmd file:

`set SPARK_HOME=C:\spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7`

`set MASTER=spark://100.79.240.26:7077`

I have not set the HADOOP_CONF_DIR and SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS (that is optional according to the documentation)

I checked the values in the Interpreter configuration page and the spark master is Ok.

When I run the Zeppelin tutorial --> "Load data into table" note I am getting a connection refused error. Here is part of the messages in the error log:

> INFO [2016-11-17 21:58:12,518] ({pool-1-thread-11} Paragraph.java[jobRun]:252) - run paragraph 20150210-015259_1403135953 using null org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter@8bbfd7
>  INFO [2016-11-17 21:58:12,518] ({pool-1-thread-11} RemoteInterpreterProcess.java[reference]:148) - Run interpreter process [C:\zeppelin-0.6.2-bin-all\bin\interpreter.cmd, -d, C:\zeppelin-0.6.2-bin-all\interpreter\spark, -p, 50163, -l, C:\zeppelin-0.6.2-bin-all/local-repo/2C3FBS414]
>  INFO [2016-11-17 21:58:12,614] ({Exec Default Executor} RemoteInterpreterProcess.java[onProcessFailed]:288) - Interpreter process failed {}
> org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 255 (Exit value: 255)
>     at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
>     at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.access$200(DefaultExecutor.java:48)
>     at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor$1.run(DefaultExecutor.java:200)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> ERROR [2016-11-17 21:58:43,846] ({Thread-49} RemoteScheduler.java[getStatus]:255) - Can't get status information
> org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>     at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:53)
>     at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:37)
>     at org.apache.commons.pool2.BasePooledObjectFactory.makeObject(BasePooledObjectFactory.java:60)
>     at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:861)
>     at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435)
>     at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
>     at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.getClient(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:189)
>     at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobStatusPoller.getStatus(RemoteScheduler.java:253)
>     at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobStatusPoller.run(RemoteScheduler.java:211)
> Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>     at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:187)
>     at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:51)
>     ... 8 more
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>     at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
>     at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
>     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
>     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
>     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
>     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
>     at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182)
>     ... 9 more
> ERROR [2016-11-17 21:58:43,846] ({pool-1-thread-11} Job.java[run]:189) - Job failed
> org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>     at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.init(RemoteInterpreter.java:165)
>     at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getFormType(RemoteInterpreter.java:328)
>     at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.getFormType(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:105)
>     at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:260)
>     at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:176)
>     at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:328)
>     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

In the Zeppelin logs there is only one file for zeppelin, the interpreter is an external Spark installation, which is not logging any error because it is never reached by the interpreter process. 

I read some suggestion about the max and min memory of the JVM but I could not fix it yet.

Any comment will be appreciated.

Paul

Comment: Usually `org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect at` means that you failed to connect to your server. Could you check again that there is no firewall issue?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I created two inbound rules in the WF, One for the port 7077 (spark master) and one for the 52063 (spark.driver.port). I tested the connectivity using Power Shell `Test-NetConnection myhost  -Port 7077 -InformationLevel "Detailed"` and the TCP Test and Ping succeeded. Still getting the same error.

Comment: I see two issues: First, Zeppelin is trxing to run your paragraph using interpreter "null". Probably a default, for better debugging it would be helpful to figure out what's happening here. Second, the Spark interpreter is started using -p 50163. I'm assuming that port information is relevant to how it tries to connect. I think your interpreter settings aren't quite correct.